# get img source (from dataURL canvas) to another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas, data-url

Sorry maybe the title isn't very clear on what I try to get done.

Let me explain.
I have a html page on which I have a button, as soon as I click the button, a php page should be run (in background). This page generates (from a database) a canvas and that canvas is turned into an encoded image (base64) and this is added to the img source of that php page (this works).
Now what I want is to get that img source and display it on the html page (where the button is).

Let me know if you need any sample code.

I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery to post the data to the PHP Page ? can you post the Javascript / jQuery code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use the .load function :

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.php', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

where `#result` is the ID of the `button` or a `div` near it .... the `ajax/test.php` would be your script and the `alert` within the `function` is the success callback (can be removed if not needed)

Comment: Here is part of the code from the php page `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;};</script></head><body><canvas id="myCanvas" width="73" height="103" style="display:none;"></canvas><? $tag = '<img id="canvasImg">'; echo $tag;?></body></html>`
I have tried to look for a good way to use jQuery, but haven't found a good sample.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the little code you posted, I would think it would look something like this, allthough not sure?

```
......
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); 
document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
document.getElementById("ImgCode").value = dataURL;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="73" height="103" style="display:none;"></canvas>

<? $tag = '<img id="canvasImg">'; 
<? $tag2 = '<input id="ImgCode" type="text">';

echo $tag;?>
echo $tag2;?>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll probably have to style and position the input tag, or replace with a div, or whatever you like really, just use innerHTML or something similar instead of value.

Comment: I've been looking into the code and removed the tag part from the code  above. I also have been playing with the code from the index page, but all I get is the input tag without its value (in the source of the php page I don't even see its value only the source of the img file) and that source is what I need to insert into an image on the index page. Here is the code of the index page: `<script type="text/javascript">function getImage(){$('#result').load('tt7.php #ImgCode');};</script><input type="button" value="Create Thumbnail" onclick="getImage();"><img id="result">`

Comment: I was thinking, maybe it has something to do with the php page not totally ready (canvas loaded and image created), maybe thats why it's empty?